# Popover UITableViewController trigger action on mainView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I have an app that gives you a popOver Tableview controller. This popOver has n number of cells. I need to be able to call a function on the main view whenever one of the table cells in the popover is touched. How would I go about doing that?

It would be nice to able to dismiss the popover too once a cell is touched....

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"Cell check %@", [totalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    [self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Here it will print the console the text in the cell, but I need to be able to pass that cell text back to the mainview... oh yeah, and the [self dismisspopoveranimated: yes] doesn't work...

Answer (score 3):

The traditional way to address this is to make your "main" view controller a delegate of the class with the table view:

1. Define an application-specific delegate protocol, add a delegate method specific to your use case, and change your "main" view controller to conform to it. The delegate method should take a parameter whose type is the data you want to pass to the "main" view controller (in your case, either a UITableViewCell or the NSString containing its text).
2. Create a property on the class with the table view whose type is the new delegate protocol.
3. Pass your "main" view controller into the class with the table view by setting it as the value of the new property.
4. When the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method is called, invoke the delegate method on the delegate you have created, passing in the data you want to give to the "main" view controller. This gives your "main" view controller an opportunity to respond to the fact that the table cell was selected in the popover, and it can call whatever function you need it to.

You can actually do the same thing in less code with blocks, but it's a bit more advanced. I won't get into that here.

You could also just use NSNotificationCenter, but personally I try to avoid using that unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: good answer. I'm interested in knowing about using blocks. Could you suggest me something?

Comment: The gist of using blocks for this approach is that instead of creating a delegate protocol and passing that into the table view class, you typedef a block type and pass a block of that type into the table view class. When the table view class needs to call back to the "main" view controller, instead of calling a delegate method on a delegate object, it simply invokes the block. One of the best introductions to Objective-C blocks is http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/ .

Comment: Thank you. So, for example, within a cell I could create a block property. Then from a tableview controller I could set a method from that block property. Then when I want to pass data from the cell to the controller, I can invoke that block method from the cell. Is it right? What about row index that I could use to update a specific cell? About the block property, is it right to define it with a copy policy? P.S. I updvoted your answer because it's very good.

Comment: Yes, you have the general idea correct. You create a block in the tableview controller, set it on the cell, and then when you want to pass data from the cell to the controller, you invoke that block. To answer your final question, you *can* use a copy policy when you declare the block property. However, I use the convention from the link I gave you in the previous comment. That is, when I create the block, I always call -copy on the block manually, and then autorelease the result, before setting it on a non-copy-policy property. One way or another, blocks must always have -copy called on them.

Comment: Thank you very much erikprice. I elaborated my thoughts in this [stackoverflow topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005052/recipes-to-pass-data-from-uitableviewcell-to-uitableviewcontroller) where I asked a question about recipes to pass data from a cell to a controller. Have a nice day!