# Not sure whether I should put logic in the UITableViewController or in the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell that has

- Two Labels
- One TextView
- One "Accept" button
- One "Delete" button

Both the accept and delete button will essentially be removing the cell. Accept changes the state of some data and it will show up on another screen and delete will remove it completely.

Here is my method to show a tableviewcell

```
- (InvitationCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"Identifier";
    InvitationCell *cell = (InvitationCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    // Create a new PFObject Object
    PFObject *connection = nil;

    connection = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    PFObject *inviterCodeName = connection[@"Inviter"];
    [inviterCodeName fetch];

    cell.inviterCodeName = inviterCodeName; // Allows us to use this in the cell
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM, h:mm a"];

    cell.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[connection updatedAt]];


    cell.codeName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invitee Code Name: %@", inviterCodeName[@"codeName"]];
    if (inviterCodeName[@"description"] == nil) {
        cell.codeNameDescription.text = @"";
    } else {
        cell.codeNameDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", inviterCodeName[@"description"]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

What I'm unsure of is whether I put the accept/reject methods in the actual UITableViewCell class or if I keep them in the class that has all of the UITableView methods?

If I keep them in the class that has all of the UITableView methods, how do I use the two buttons in the custom cell? Do I make outlets to them? Is there another delegate method I need to use?

Comment: tableviewcell is a view it should be concerned only with what user is viewing

Comment: delegation is the best way.delegation MVC suits best here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About your first question I would say the following. Do not **NOT** put logic within a `UITableViewCell`. A cell is not a controller but a view. So, it should not have logic inside. The controller is the correct place.

A good discussion on it can be found in [UITableViewCell Is Not a Controller](http://inessential.com/2012/12/31/uitableviewcell_is_not_a_controller). I really suggest to read it.

About the second discussion, you can follow few ways. For example, you can register actions directly in the controller or use delegate pattern. I would prefer the latter one since it's more clear to me. But this is personal taste. For example it allows to reuse these cells within another controller that performs similar operations.

This is an old discussion on how to achieve it. But it still remains valid. [Recipes to pass data from UITableViewCell to UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005052/recipes-to-pass-data-from-uitableviewcell-to-uitableviewcontroller).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think I need to read up more on delegates and creating my own. This is the path I think I will take. I'm just not familiar with delegates yet.

Answer (score 2):

In your InvitationCell.h file add below properties.

```
@property NSIndexPath *indexPath;
```

And add delegate method as.

```
-(void)deleteButtonClickedForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(void)acceptButtonClickedForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

In your tableView controller, **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method add below lines of code

```
cell.delegate=self;
cell.indexPath = indexPath;
```

Add delegate methods to your controller and work around them based on indexPath value.